# Apple Push Notifications and General UX Strategy -- what's the most sound approach for notifying users via an atypical route?

Tags: macos, cocoa, design-patterns, apple-push-notifications, user-experience

I'm working on a small Mac OS X utility that provides notification of some events via an atypical route, UX-wise — it sends a message to an external lamp via a ZigBee interface — and I am curious about how best to approach the Apple Push Notification stack. I've already written the meat of the utility (serial port interface over USB, a stateful daemon w/ `CFRunLoop`, etc) but what remains is to tie it in to actual events.

I have not yet written code that interfaces with APNs of any sort. If I want my utility to react when e.g. the user receives an email, what approach makes the most sense? Do I:

- Run my own email-polling service from which to emit APNs to the client?
- Subscribe to APNs emitted by an existent service?
- Programmatically talk to the OS X Notification Center app/service/widget itself?
- Avoid APNs altogether in favor of some other route (e.g. a Mail.app plugin or some other API)?

It's a general question, to be sure — but I am not at all sure of the feasibility of any of these approaches, and I'd appreciate any basic guidance anyone with experience in this specific arena might have to offer. Thanks!